# How to debugging a Python code for understading answer?

Tags: python, debugging

I trying to learn python, and saw this code unfortunately I couldn't figure out why the result got to 33!!!

What's the debugging? someone told me that helping your finding answer, but I don't know how to do that for finding answer.

This is my current code

```html
x = "c"
y = 3
if "x" in "computer science":
    y = y + 5
else:
    y = y + 10
if x in "computer science":
    y = y + 20
else:
    y = y + 40
print (y)
```

Comment: I guess you mean [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html)? You can use it to step through your program, but ["print debugging"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225243/is-printing-to-console-stdout-a-good-debugging-strategy) is also often used to see in which branches of ifs your code steps.

Answer (score 0):

In your 3rd line you typed `"x"` instead of `x` which means that you're looking for a `x` string in "computer science", which isn't there, so your code adds 10 to `y` instead of 5

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy
The first conditional `if "x" in "computer science":` is looking for the string `"x"` in the string `"computer science"`.  Notice the quotes around the x.  This means it's a string literal and not the variable x.

This means that the `else` code block is executed, adding `10` to the value of `y` (which is 3 before this.)

Value of `y` is now `int(13)`

Then, the second conditional `if x in "computer science"` is looking for the value of the variable `x` in the string literal `"computer science"`.  Since the value of variable `x` is the string literal `"c"`, and there are three "c"'s in "computer science": the conditional evaluates to True and the first code block is executed.

This first code block adds 20 to the value of `y`, which was `int(13)`.  Thus, `y` ends up being `3 + 10 + 20` (33)

Answer (score 0):

`y` is initialised to `3`. The first `if` statement checks to see if the character `x` is in the string `computer science`, it isn't, so we add `10` to `y`. `y` is now equal to 13. In the second `if` statement checks whether the value of the variable `x` which is `c`, this is in the string `computer science`, so we add `20` to `y`.

`y` is therefore `33`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

here is the reason, in your first if statement

```
x = "c" #x is a variable containing a string 'c'
y = 3
if "x" in "computer science":
# in this if statement the condition checked if the string x is in "computer science" it didn't check the variable x, just a string 'x' so this statement below will not be executed since the condition is not satisfied
    y = y + 5
else: # but this one will be executed since it is the else statement and the if statement is not satisfied which will overwrite the value of y from 3 to 13
    y = y + 10
so now the value of y=13

#in your second if statement
if x in "computer science":
#you checked if the variable x is in computer science which basically is true because its is the same as asking 'is 'c' in computer science' so the statement mellow will be executed which will overwrite the value of y from 13 to 33 so when you print y you will get 3
    y = y + 20
else:
    y = y + 40
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. and as my opinion it is a good idea to put print statements to understand what is going on for example putting a print statement after the first if statement would make things a bit clear.

Comment: Actually I thought this is just a block :                                                          if "x" in "computer science":
    y = y + 5
else:
    y = y + 10                                                                                                         and first "IF" didn't "True", next block should run.

Comment: That is why the else statements runs if I have understood your question well, since the first if statement wasn't satisfied the else statment will be executed  before executing  the next line of code.

Comment: Actually I start learning code recently and decided to learn with Python. I will be appreciate if you can help me more about it... if you have extra time of course.

Comment: I will be happy to help in a ways I can but I am a home learning starter as you are, still we could help each other in a ways, how do you want it to go.

Comment: As you mentioned I'm learning at home, I don't know how can I reach you, I'll happy to do that

Comment: Can I have your email adress,That way we could talk.

Answer (score 0):

->   if "x" in "computer science":   This means if substring "x"(here it is in double quotes, so it will be treated as a string) is in the string "computer science" then execute the if block code. Since "x" is not in "computer science", the folowing else block will be executed that is

```
else:
y = y + 10
```

thus after this y = 13

-> Now again the other if block will be check its condition that is

```
if x in "computer science":
    y = y + 20
else:
    y = y + 40
```

Here, in this block of code x is treated as a variable that store "c" and since in "computer science" there is "c"(at first character place), the if block code will be executed updating value of y = 13 to y = 13+20 = 33

-> In simple words, Debugging means to identify and remove errors from the code.
 You can refer to this link for more info on debugging https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the detailed explanation (the one requiring only your brain). wrt/ debugging tools etc, there are at least two that can help you tracing code execution (which is the point).

The first one is dead simple, it's named "print". All you have to do is to add some `print()` whithin your code to find out which parts are executed (and from deduction which aren't) and what values your variables have at those points:

```
x = "c"
y = 3

print('start : x = "{}", y = {}'.format(x, y))

if "x" in "computer science":
    y = y + 5
    print('"x" in "computer science" - now y = {}'.format(y))
else:
    y = y + 10
    print('"x" not in "computer science" - now y = {}'.format(y))
if x in "computer science":
    y = y + 20
    print('x ( = "{}") in "computer science" - now y = {}'.format(x, y))
else:
    y = y + 40
    print('x ( = "{}") not in "computer science" - now y = {}'.format(x, y))
print (y)
```

which when executed will display:

```
start : x = "c", y = 3
"x" not in "computer science" - now y = 13
x ( = "c") in "computer science" - now y = 33
33
```

The other tool is named a step debugger and is a bit more complex (but much more powerful). [Python comes with a (command line) step debugger included](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), it might not be as "sexy" as a GUI one but requires zero installation, zero configuration, and is garanteed to work in all environments. (nb I'm not going to explain how to use it here since it's already documented...)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

```
if "x" in "computer science":
if x in "computer science":
```

here is the answer. x is different from "x"